# Using Highrise API Wrapper

Tags: php, api, highrise

Good Day.

I am trying my hardest to get my mind around PHP for building an site where you can see Highrise events printed out.

Found this wrapper, but do not know how to use it, what i should write to get use of this wrapper.

Please Help.

http://101tec.com/en/open-source/highrise-api-wrapper is the link for the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this Highrise API wrapper/library:
https://github.com/ignaciovazquez/Highrise-PHP-Api

Looks more developed, with example code.